# Spring Boot - Not able to send email

Tags: spring, email, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when I send email from my Spring Boot app.

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client
>   does not have permissions to send as this sender

And below are my application properties:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.username = my.email@company.com
spring.mail.password = password
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
```

Comment: And below is my application.properties:
spring.mail.host = smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.username = my.email@company.com
spring.mail.password = password
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true

Comment: You do not have permissions; investigate that.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to reply. This is the email address I send email from. So I should have permission.

Comment: Found the solution. I needed the following three lines in the application.properties file:  
  
spring.mail.port = 587  
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true  
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. That account still didn't work. But I was able to make it work with gmail by adding the following in application.properties file: 
`code`  
#for gmail. 
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = userId@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = password
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is a firewall starting which  blocked gmail